# How to configure TFS burndown chart to be for effort points not task hours?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, burndowncharts

My question is really simple, hopefully the answer will be too.

You all know the task burndown in TFS online right ? Here's an example

[image]

Obviously, the y-axis is the remaining hours of tasks. I want to change that to be the remaining effort points of Product Backlog Items and Bugs.

Can I do that ? If so, How ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You have to edit the "Sprint Burndown.rdl" file in your process template (it's in the reports folder). Particularly, you have to change this field:

```
<Field Name="Remaining_Work">
      <DataField>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;Field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="Measure" UniqueName="[Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork]" /&gt;</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
</Field>
```

To reference the effort point field. This isn't the only change that you'll need to make to that file to get this to work (the MEASURE in the SELECT statement also needs to be altered), but that should at least get you started.

Comment: can this be done on Team Foundation Service online ? or is it only Team Foundation Server ?

Comment: Cannot be done on TF Service. You cannot alter the process template at all there. The alternative in that case would be to use an Excel report. If your question pertains only to TF Service, please remove the extra TFS tags attached to your question.

Comment: @davenewza: Visual Studio Online is the rebranded post-beta version of TF Service, so the answer is still no.