# tfs Story Point history for User Stories

Tags: report, user-stories

I need to find out the history of Story Points for each User Story work Item and possibly display that in a TFS report. Any idea of how the SQL Query might look?

The goal is to find out if and by how much Story Points were changed between Iteration planning and Start to finish of an Iteration.

Thank you for the help folks!

Comment: But i am trying to look at what was the Story Point number that was changed on the User Stories (for example a User Story changed from 5 to 8) rather than a Story Point Burndown for that iteration. Just making sure we are on the same page. Is that possible with your above suggested solution. I haven't tried it yet, to test it.

Answer (score 0):

For your needs, you could try to configure TFS burndown chart to be for effort points instead of task hours.

You have to edit the "Sprint Burndown.rdl" file in your process template (it's in the reports folder). Particularly, you have to change this field:

```
<Field Name="Remaining_Work">
      <DataField>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;Field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="Measure" UniqueName="[Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork]" /&gt;</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
</Field>
```

More details please refer this question: [How to configure TFS burndown chart to be for effort points not task hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256414/how-to-configure-tfs-burndown-chart-to-be-for-effort-points-not-task-hours)

And you can also create your own report based on TFS data (warehouse or cube).Such as using Excel Reports (TFS), from that you can track your team project's burn rate, bug backlog, software quality, test progress, and other metrics by viewing a default [Excel report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd997876.aspx).  More info on MSDN: [Dashboards and reports overview](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/overview)

Comment: I saw this post and tried to use the info. I replaced all occurances with "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints" (my Story Point column). Unfortunately I don't know how to set the query to count userstories and bugs. How would I need to replace this line? StrToSet("[Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].[Task]"). Further more, can you tell me if there is anything else to do but replacing that line and all the occurances of the remainingwork field?

Comment: @Partick. But i am trying to look at what was the Story Point number that was changed on the User Stories (for example a User Story changed from 5 to 8) rather than a Story Point Burndown for that iteration. Just making sure we are on the same page. Is that possible with your above suggested solution. I haven't tried it yet, to test it.